# Creating an arrow-flow-effect using two tables of X and Y coordinates respectively

Tags: plotting

I have two tables. One table contains X-coordinates and the other contains corresponding Y-coordinates (please see the diagram attached).

What I am trying to achieve is the arrow-flow-effect also shown in the attached diagram. So, to clarify, together each column of the tables creates a distinct path of numerous arrows.

**EDIT:**

I have applied kglr's method for a single column, but still need a way to automate across columns. As you will see from the code in the second image, I need something that can overcome the need to manually implement kglr's method for each column:

[image]

How can I achieve the described effect in an automated way?[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want an arrow for each link in the path, you could make each link into an arrow and display them with graphics.

To illustrate the method, create some data as a stand-in for one column of your tables

```
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10];
y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10];
points = Transpose[{x, y}];
```

then show the path with arrows:

```
Graphics[Arrow /@ Partition[points, 2, 1]]
```

[image: arrows along a path]

Repeat and combine for other columns in the tables.

Comment: how do I set the size of the arrows when the creation of the arrow path is automatic? Where can I put the styling information?

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[7777]

n = 7;

{x, y} = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, n}];

colors = RandomColor[n - 1];

styledarrows = Transpose[{colors, BlockMap[Arrow, Transpose[{x, y}], 2, 1]}];

Graphics[{Arrowheads[Large], Thick, styledarrows}]
```

[image]